UNIQUE constraint failed: customuser.username
im trying to understand the drf.
I´ve set up all the endpoints and they work, the only thing that doesnt work is when i want to post something to my database, the first Post goes well and then the second one shows an integrity error, ive been stuck now for a few days haha
Could somebody help me understand what i am missing here
models.py :
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email  = models.EmailField(default ="no email")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25 ,default = 'No name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25, default = 'No surname')
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 25,default = "no password")
    
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

views.py
class CustomModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_list(request,format =None):
    #get all users
    #serialize them
    #return json
    if request.method == 'GET':
        allUser = CustomUser.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializer(allUser, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    elif request.method =='POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET','PUT','DELETE'])       
def user_detail(request,id,format =None):
    try:
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=id)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

serializers.py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['id','email','password','first_name','last_name']

TRACEBACK:
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/model-viewset/

Django Version: 5.0.2
Python Version: 3.12.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'aao_app',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The above exception (UNIQUE constraint failed: aao_app_customuser.username) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\mixins.py", line 24, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 679, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 78, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 822, in save
    self.save_base(
    ^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 909, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1067, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1108, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1823, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 122, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in _execute
    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Giuli\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 329, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /model-viewset/
    Exception Value: UNIQUE constraint failed: aao_app_customuser.username


Try to run the server in another port, for example python manage.py runserver 8001

@SunderamDubey , it shows the same error, doesnt work unfortunatly

Provide the full error traceback.

I´ve provided it now :)

do you already have data in your database ?

Besides a superuser, no

When you inherit from AbstractUser class, you inherit class properties/fields too such as email, username etc.
link
username is required and set to be Unique by default.
To change it, you should set username to None:
username = None

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email  = models.EmailField(default ="no email")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25 ,default = 'No name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 25, default = 'No surname')
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 25,default = "no password")
    username = None

Then, do makemigrations and migrate.

Cant it be replaced/override

Ah i see thank you, but now he says the following:  CustomUser has no field named 'username'
Thats what we want, no?
Why cant i makemigrations :D

@BDurand it should be possible, but I think it is not what OP is trying to do
